# Splunk breakdown results by matched search phrase

Tags: splunk

I'm searching for a few different search terms, and I would like stats grouped by which term matched:

```
"PhraseA" "PhraseB" "PhraseC" | timechart count by <which Phrase matched>
```

What should be in place of `<which Phrase matched>`? I will be building a stacked bar chart with the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try creating a category field using eval and case, and using that in your chart:

```
index=whatever_index "PhraseA" "PhraseB" "PhraseC"
| eval matched_phrase=case(searchmatch("PhraseA"), "PhraseA", searchmatch("PhraseB"), "PhraseB", searchmatch("PhraseC"), "PhraseC")
| timechart count by matched_phrase
```

Lots more good info in the [Splunk documentation](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.1/SearchReference/Commonevalfunctions) for these functions